# CDATA not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cdata

hi the following simple javascript not working in chrome.

```
<script>
var str=(<r><![CDATA[test]]></r>).toString();
alert(str);
</script>
```

it works in FF and pops the dialog. in Chrome it throws this error.
Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected token <

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML). From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_e4x.asp):

> Firefox is currently the only browser with relatively good support for E4X.
>
> There are [sic] currently no support for E4X in Opera, Chrome, or Safari.
>
> So far there is no indication for of E4X support in Internet Explorer.